# Show 3 latest posts on homepage rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, haml

I saw some similar questions but didn't success with this.
I want to display the 3 latest posts on my homepage.

I define this method on my PostsController

```
def noticia
    @posts = Posts.all(:limit => 3)
  end
  helper_method :noticia
```

and I invoke this on my view

```
- if @noticia
  %h4.feed
    A Sair
    %h6
      %span= @noticia.created_at.strftime("%d %b. %Y")
      = link_to @noticia.content, posts_path
    %p
      - if current_admin
        = link_to "Adicionar notícia", new_post_path
```

It gives NoMethodError

```
undefined method `each' for #<Post:0x00000102fb6fc8>
```

Comment: Is there a limit on the default scope?

Comment: Are you referring to @posts in your view?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a lot of strange things in your code.

Your `noticia` method should be :

```
def noticia
  @posts = Post.order("created_at desc").limit(3)
end
```

You don't need to use `helper_method`.

And your view file must be something like :

```
- if @posts.any?
  - @posts.each do |post|
     = # do something with my post
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 2):

```
@posts = Post.order('created_at').limit(3)

@posts = Post.order('created_at DESC').limit(3)

@posts = Post.order('created_at ASC').limit(3)
```

Comment: I already set the default_scope on my Post model. The problem is that I just can't invoke the latest 3 elements

Comment: This won't work. => `undefined method 'order' for #<Array:xxx>`. You must remove the call to the `all` method.

Comment: @JohnMcKey thanks for the heads up. I updated the code example.

Answer (score 0):

Is your model 'Post' (not Posts)?

This is how you'd use limit with ActiveRecord.

```
def noticia
  @posts = Post.limit(3)
end
```